# Understanding the delta Neural Networks

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network

I am currently following a blog post in Neural Networks and there he used a syntax which I cant understand
his code was

```
delta = self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], y) * \ sigmoid_prime(zs[-1])
```

[image]

can anyone help me to know what he is trying to tell in that line of code because what deos it mean to have **' \ '** after **' * '**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash (`\`) in python is for line breaks. If there is a large line, it can be split into smaller ones by adding a backslash

Answer (score 1):

the backslash simply means that the line of code continues under it.
That line is basically equivalent to this:

```
delta = self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], y) * sigmoid_prime(zs[-1])
```

Comment: Glad to help! :)